# How to configure a UIScrollView content size to have a fixed width and a dynamic height?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a UIScrollView contained in another container view with constraints set to take all the space of the container view. That is to say that I don't have a fixed width or height on the scroll view.
In my scroll view I programmatically add subviews. Each subview (content view) is loaded from a xib.
In the xib I set an arbitrary size to the root view (500x500) but I would like that view width to be automatically resized to the scroll view width (the scroll view width being the container width).
I don't want the user to be able to scroll horizontally.

I tried different solutions always resulting in the scroll view being scrollable horizontally.
I tried to tweak the content view hugging and compression property to different values on the horizontal axis with no success.

I don't want to set fixed widths on my views because I want them to take the width of the container view.

Thanks in advance if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Late answer with what I came up with at that time.
As I'm using Autolayout, VChemezov answer is not really satisfying.

My content views have a top, bottom, leading, width set of constraints. (width instead of trailing which is what I was doing in the first place but it was not working).

So now I have something like this:

```
        NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                       constraintWithItem:messageView
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                       toItem:self.conversationScrollView
                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                       multiplier:1.0f
                                       constant:0.0f];
        NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                        constraintWithItem:messageView
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.conversationScrollView
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                        multiplier:1.0f
                                        constant:0.0f];
        [self.conversationScrollView addConstraints:@[ top, leading, width ]];
```

With the width of the content view equal to the width of the scroll view.

Comment: This helped me, and I just wanted to add that you can replicate this behavior in Storyboards by having your inner view (messageView in this case) attached to all four sides of the scrollView, but then adding an equal widths constraint to the scrollView. If the scrollView is attached to the superview, this will automatically set the width of the contentView to the width of the superview. Handles orientation updates as well.

Answer (score 2):

Autolayout will not adjust view size inside UIScrolView. You should layout and resize this views by yourself. There is two basic solutions:

- Explicitly set width of subview before adding it to UIScrollView
- Subclass UIScrollView and override **setFrame** and **layoutSubviews** like this

  ```
  @implementation MyScrollView

  - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
      [super setFrame:frame];
      [self setNeedsLayout];
  }

  - (void)layoutSubviews{
      [super layoutSubviews];
      NSArray * subviews=self.subviews;
      for(UIView * view in subviews){
          CGRect viewFrame=view.frame;
          viewFrame.size.width=self.bounds.size.width;
          view.frame=viewFrame;
      }
  }

  @end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SnapKit` it is even faster:

```
let helper = UIView()
scrollView.addSubview(helper)

helper.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.width.equalTo(snp.width)
    make.leading.trailing.top.equalToSuperview()
    make.height.equalTo(0)
}
```

Comment: +1 because it is definitely the way to go now. 2014 => 2017. Use SnapKit or PureLayout but don't use native Autolayout API (unless you have too much time).